# Сортировка в MySQL по нескольких полям

Tags: сортировка, mysql

У меня есть таблица, в которой есть поля **active** и **last_active_time**
В них сохраняются индекс активности и время последнего события соответственно.
Мне нужно сделать сортировку по столбцу **active** по убыванию, если значения строк одинаковые, то сортировать по **last_active_time** по убыванию
Как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY active DESC, last_active_time DESC` ? В чем сложность-то?